# Using mapStateToProps in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to get a simple example to work. Here is the code below.

In this example, in:

`mapStateToProps = (state) => {}`

where is `state` coming from? I am little confused as to what exactly I am passing into?

I understand that `connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoApp)` "binds" the state returned in `mapStateToProps` to `TodoApp` and can then be accessed via `this.props`.

What do I need to do to this code so I can print out the current state inside `TodoApp`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'


const stateObject = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'eric'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'john'
    }
]

const todo = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return {
                id: action.id,
                text: action.text
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}


const todos = (state = stateObject, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [
                ...state,
                todo(undefined, action)
            ];
        default:
            return state
    }
}



const store = createStore(todos)

//confused by what is happening here
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        ?: ?
    }
}

const TodoApp = () => {
    //How do I get this to print out the current props?
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
        <div>
            Some Text
        </div>
    )
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoApp)


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <TodoApp />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Ok updated:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        names: state
    }
}

const TodoApp = () => {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
        <div>
            Some Text1
        </div>
    )
}

const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoApp);


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <ConnectedComponent />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

However I'm still getting `undefined` for `console.log(this.props)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mapStateToProps = (state) => {}` - `state` is the current value of your redux store.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. When I run `console.log(this.props)` inside `TodoApp` how come it is coming back as undefined? Inside `mapStateToProps` I return `{users: state}`

Comment: There's no `this` with a functional component. You can change it to `const TodoApp = (props) => {` to access the props.

Comment: ding ding ding, chicken dinner we have a winner. Thank you! I'm new to "functional" programming and forgot that.

Comment: if you put this in an answer I can mark it as correct

Comment: cool, just added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `this` with a functional component. To access the props you can change it to this:

```
const TodoApp = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div>
            Some Text1
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mapStateToProps` maps the some parts of your Redux state to props of your React Component.

State comes from your `store`. In fact, you can take a look at your current state at any point by calling `store.getState()`. When you do `createStore(todos)`, this creates the state based on the `todos` reducer. As you can see in your `todos` reducer, your initial state comes from `stateObject`, which is defined up top.

So, back to `mapStateToProps`. All you need to do in that functions is to return the object, where keys will be the props and values will be the values obtained from the Redux state. Here's an example of `mapStateToProps`:

```js
const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    return {
        propName: state
    }
}
```

Now when you do the `console.log(this.props)` inside render(), you can see the whole state being stored inside `this.props.propName`. That is achieved by `mapStateToProps`.

A little bit of theory on this: each time an action is dispatched, every `mapStateToProps` you have in your app is called, props are applied to every component you created, and if any props have changed, that component will re-render. This kind of behaviour is provided for you via `connect` function. So you don't have to implement this behaviour for every component: all you need to do is to apply it like so: `const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(SomeComponent)` and use `ConnectedComponent` instead of `SomeComponent`.

Comment: great answer, very helpful. I implemented your suggestions but I'm still getting `undefined` for `console.log(this.props)`. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A functional component won't have `this.props` - it just has `props` as its one parameter to the function.

Comment: @MorganAllen, the official documentation suggest that you have presentational and container components, where containers are defined as classes, while presentational are functions. I believe you can only do `connect` on class-like components defined like this: `class TodoApp extends React.Component { ... }`. I don't think you can do `connect` on components defined as functions like in your code `const TodoApp = () => { ... }`.

Comment: @guitarino: that's wrong.  First, it's fine to have class-type components that are "presentational" in nature.  Second, `connect()` doesn't care whether you passed it a component written using classes, functions, or the old-style `createClass`.

Comment: @markerikson, I'm aware that it's fine to have class-type presentational components, I just said that's what the official documentation suggests. But thanks for the `connect()` comment; I stand corrected.